# Subdomain Integration Testing With Nodejs and Supertest

Tags: node.js, jestjs

How to write integration tests for a multi-tenant app with subdomain.

I am working on a multi-tenant application. I am trying to write integration tests for a subdomain but can't seem to get it working.

Here is what I have done:

*test file*

```
import supertest from 'supertest';
import http from 'http';
import app from '../../../app';

const baseUrl = 'censio.lvh.me:7000';

describe('Censio tests', () => {
  let server;
  let request;

  beforeAll((done) => {
    server = http.createServer(app);
    server.listen(7000, done);
    request = supertest(server);
  });

  afterAll((done) => {
    server.close(done);
  });

  describe('Signin', () => {
    it('should respond with missing fields ...', async () => {
      const response = await request
        .post(`${baseUrl}/signin`)
        .send({})
        .set('Accept', 'application/json');

      expect(response.status).toBe(400);
    });
  });
});
```

*app.js*

```
import '@babel/polyfill';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import express from 'express';
import subdomain from 'express-subdomain';
import censioRouter from './tenants/censio';

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

// Subdomain definitions
app.use(subdomain('censio', censioRouter));

app.get('*', (req, res) => res.status(200).json({ message: 'Project started' }));

export default app;
```

When I check response.text I see
    `<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang=\"en\">
        <head>
        <meta charset=\"utf-8\">
        <title>Error</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <pre>Cannot POST /:7000censio.lvh.me/signin</pre>
        </body>
        </html>`

It puts the post in front. When I get rid of the port, I receive this error: `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80`

What do I do?

Answer (score 3):

I finally got it to work. I am posting this for whoever may need this solution in the future.

- First, I gained full understanding of how to use a custom domain to test my application locally. I had to modify my `/etc/hosts` file. [This post](https://www.imore.com/how-edit-your-macs-hosts-file-and-why-you-would-want) helped me with that.
- I modified my tests (as seen in my question above). Instead of passing `app` to supertest, I passed the base url I wanted i.e my url containing my subdomain(censio.mydomain.com:myport). This is how it looks like now.

  ```
  import supertest from 'supertest';
  import http from 'http';
  import app from '../../../app';

  describe('Censio tests', () => {
    describe('Signin', () => {
      let server;
      let request;

      beforeAll((done) => {
        server = http.createServer(app);
        server.listen(7000, done);
        request = supertest('http://censio.mydomain.com:7000');
      });

      afterAll((done) => {
        server.close(done);
      });

      it('should respond with missing fields ...', async () => {
        const response = await request
          .post('/signin')
          .send({})
          .set('Accept', 'application/json');

        expect(response.status).toBe(400);
      });
    });
   });
  ```

Notice I changed where I am calling my before and after hooks.

I hope this helps you as it helped me.